# Routing guards in Framework 7 Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, html-framework-7

When I do the following:

```
{
      path: '/chat/',
      async(routeTo, routeFrom, resolve, reject) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
          resolve({
            component: require('./assets/vue/pages/chat.vue'),
          });
        } else {
          resolve({
            component: LoginPage
          });
        }
      },
    }
```

Everything works as expected, but if I do this:

```
{
      path: '/chat/',
      component: require('./assets/vue/pages/chat.vue'),
      async(routeTo, routeFrom, resolve, reject) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
          resolve();
        } else {
          resolve({
            component: LoginPage
          });
        }
      },
    }
```

Then the component always resolves, regardless of the async. This is also the case when I try to use a `beforeEnter` function instead of async; if the component is defined at the top level of the route, it always resolves.

How could I put an authentication middleware on a route?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this.

```
const checkAuth = (to, from, resolve, reject) => {
   if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
     resolve({ component: routeComponentMap[to.name] })
   } else {
     resolve({ component: LoginPage })
   }
}

const routeComponentMap = {
  CHAT: require('./assets/vue/pages/chat.vue')
}

const routes = [{
  path: "/chat/",
  name: "CHAT",
  async: checkAuth
}]
```